# PHP $_Get is not receiving querystring value

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm creating a dropdown menu that sends a "country code" to PHP file which queries MySQL.  This then generates an html table.  Everything seems to work except that $_GET always receives nothing.  Even when I hard code the querystring to a code.  What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <title>Test</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function showCountry(str) {
             if (str == "") {
              document.getElementById("SurveyContainer").innerHTML = "";
              return;
             }
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } 
            else {  // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("SurveyContainer").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET", "getSurveys.php?q=" + str, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="countries" onchange="showCountry(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select Country:</option>
        <option value="WW">WW</option>
        <option value="AU">AU</option>
        <option value="USA">USA</option>
    </select>

    <div id="SurveyContainer"><b>Survey table</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

getSurveys.php:

```
<?php

//Get Country Code
$q = ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['q'] ) ) ? intval( $_GET['q'] ) :'WW';

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','myusername','mypassword','mydatabase');

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"mydatabase");

$sql="SELECT * FROM tblSurveys WHERE country = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table class='surveytable'>";
echo "<tr><th width='61'>Country</th><th>Link To Join Paying Survey Panel Web Site</th><th>About Survey Panel</th><th width='93'>Survey Incentives</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td><b>$row[country]</b></td><td><a href='$row[link]' target='_blank'>$row[name]</a></td><td>$row[description] </td><td>$row[incentives]</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";　

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you invoke your script directly from the browser URL bar, does it work?

Comment: FYI, you have no form tag. Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: Please fix your `getSurveys.php` content. I mean `mypassword'`.

Comment: @JohnConde - A form element isn't required.

Comment: what does <?php print_r($_GET); ?> show you?

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with and without the form tag. same result.

Comment: add an echo '>>'.$_GET['q'].'<<'; in top of php the see result

Comment: $_GET['q'] receives a 0 which I assume is Nothing or Null?

Comment: I'd go with trueicecold. See what print_r shows you. What does firebug net panel say has been sent? Are there any errors in the JS panel?

Comment: I think you have a problem in your path : 'getSurveys.php?q='+str try with a canonical link to see if this is the problem, something like  : 'http://localhost/mysite/getSurveys.php?q='+str

Comment: I have setup the html - copied/pasted and set getSurveys.php as just print'<pre>';print_r($_GET);print'</pre>'; and it works fine - it outputs it correctly. Your code doesn't look wrong!

Comment: Which browser are you testing this on? Does it make any difference to use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` instead of `this.value` in `onchange="showCountry()"`?

Comment: Are you saying that if you go directly to your `getSurveys.php?q=test` page in your browser that page by itself will not `print_r()` > `[q] => test`?

Comment: Great advice from all. I used a little bit from everyone. I still wasn't getting the results I wanted and was baffled until I realized my cache wasn't being cleared and I never wasn't looking at my changes. DoH! I cleared my browser cache and voila it worked! So I am not completely sure which or if not all of your answers helped but thank you to all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what value you are checking: `$q` or `$_GET['q']`, but the logic at the top of your php script is wrong:

```
$q = ( isset( $_GET['q'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['q'] ) ) ? intval( $_GET['q'] ) :'WW';
```

You are checking for a numeric value and casting to an integer while the value of your query string is either nothing or a country code string.

So your actual `$_GET['q']` value will never be used in your script.

You only need:

```
$q = isset( $_GET['q'] ) ? $_GET['q'] :'WW';
```

And then you would need a prepared statement (or `mysqli_real_escape_string()`...) to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Great advice from all.  I used a little bit from everyone.  I still wasn't getting the results I wanted and was baffled until I realized my cache wasn't being cleared and I never wasn't looking at my changes. DoH!  I cleared my browser cache and voila it worked!  So I am not completely sure which or if not all of your answers helped but thank you to all!